# How to run a macro in response to a trigger as in the case of a snippet insertion?

Tags: macros, sublimetext2

I have recorded a macro in the file `mymacro.sublime-macro`. It moves the cursor back by one space and then inserts `_{}`.

I want this macro to be triggered when I type `subn` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: why not just assign a key binding to it?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I tried the following `[
    {"keys": ["subn","tab"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "../tempsubscript.sublime-macro"}}
]`, but that does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a more exhaustive search of the documentation, I found the following way to bind a command to a word followed by `tab`. For example, the problem I stated un my question above can be solved by:

```
{ "keys": ["s","u","b","n","tab"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/tempsubscript.sublime-macro"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following key binding:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/mymacro.sublime-macro"} }
```

Now, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (or whatever keybinding you choose), the macro will be triggered.

Comment: I want to bind it to a word + tab key as done when we insert snippets. For example, when I type "subn" and press tab, it should run the macro file.